# fire a function when all image download complete

Tags: jquery

i am downloading images in each iteration. so logic & code is there in each iterator which download image one by one. i want that when all images download gets completed then immediately i want to call a function which notify user that all images download complete.
please guide me to modify my existing code.

here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("table[id*=dgImages] img").each(function () {
if($(this).offset().top > $(window).scrollTop() && $(this).offset().top < $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) {


$(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("original"));
$(this).removeAttr("original");
}
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery deferred objects to the rescue:

```
var def = [];                  // an array to store deferred objects

$('img').each(function() {     // for each image
   var d = $.Deferred();       // create a new deferred object
   def.push(d);                // store it in the array for later
   $(this).load(d.resolve);    // and on load, "resolve" it
});

$.when.apply($, def)           // $.when(def[0], def[1], ...);
.then(function() {             // are all resolved, then
    alert("all loaded!");      // do your stuff here
});
```

Comment: i have bit confusion regarding code u gave. what $.Deferred() will store in d? d.resolve will return image path or anything different? $.when.apply($, def).then(function()  will call automatically when all images download? my requirement was like that suppose i have 100 images to download but i will download only 10 images and when user scroll down then next 10 images will download. so i need to know that when 10 images download gets completed out of 100 then when.apply() will fire or not? please discuss in detail....merry chrismas & thanks

Comment: @user750398 you probably need to read http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/ to understand how the deferred objects work.  re: only 10 at a time - that's a _much_ harder problem.